# Can I run batch script on windows machine through remote WMI?

Tags: linux, batch-file, wmi

I would like to run remote scripts on windows machine and one of the access point I have is WMI.
Is it possible to so? What kind of privileges do I need
Another issue is that I am running from a Linux machine

Any information would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Impacket (https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket) you can execute commands from Linux on target Windows machines using the following scripts:

1) https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket/blob/master/examples/wmiexec.py: A similar approach to psexec but executing commands through WMI.

2) https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket/blob/master/examples/psexec.py: PSEXEC like functionality example using RemComSvc (https://github.com/kavika13/RemCom)

3) https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket/blob/master/examples/smbexec.py: A similar approach to psexec w/o using RemComSvc. The technique is described here http://www.accuvant.com/blog/owning-computers-without-shell-access

4) https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket/blob/master/examples/atexec.py: Executes commands at the target system using Windows Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

[winexe](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ahajda:/winexe/) worked for me to run a Windows console script remotely from my Linux box.  Syntax:

```
winexe --user adminuser --password password //computername c:/path/to/script.bat
```

You can even get an interactive session going with something like this:

```
winexe --user adminuser --password password //computername cmd.exe
```

Admin rights on the Windows box are needed for remote access.  Also, be advised that if the Windows scripts you intend to run contain relative paths, they might get confused and say "File not found".  Use absolute paths in your scripts.

I also tried wmi-client (wmic) without any luck, getting a bunch of RPC errors after a long wait, but the build I tried was old.  You might have better luck, but I don't even know if the `process call create` syntax is even supported at all.  It might just be WQL `select` queries only, as far as the documentation indicates.

If `winexe` isn't for you, then you could install an SSH service on your Windows box with cygwin or similar.